# 2 radio buttons a la vez

Tags: html, css, web, ionic, radiobutton

Estoy programando con ionic y puse 2 botones de radio, sin embargo después de poner el mismo atributo de nombre aún es posible seleccionar 2 al mismo tiempo

Código:

```
   <ion-item>
       <ion-label>¿Facturar?</ion-label>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
       <ion-label class="ion-margin-end">si</ion-label>
       <ion-radio slot="start" value="si" name="facturar"></ion-radio>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
       <ion-label class="ion-margin-end">no</ion-label>
       <ion-radio slot="start" value="no" name="facturar"></ion-radio>
   </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes envolver los `radio-button` dentro de `ion-radio-group`

```
<ion-radio-group value="facturar">
   <ion-item>
       <ion-label>¿Facturar?</ion-label>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
       <ion-label class="ion-margin-end">si</ion-label>
       <ion-radio slot="start" value="si" name="facturar"></ion-radio>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
       <ion-label class="ion-margin-end">no</ion-label>
       <ion-radio slot="start" value="no" name="facturar"></ion-radio>
   </ion-item>
</ion-radio-group>
```